# Is file object in python an iterable

Tags: python, iterable

I have a file "test.txt":

```
this is 1st line
this is 2nd line
this is 3rd line
```

the following code

```
lines = open("test.txt", 'r')
for line in lines:
    print "loop 1:"+line
for line in lines:
    print "loop 2:"+line
```

only prints:

```
loop 1:this is 1st line

loop 1:this is 2nd line

loop 1:this is 3rd line
```

It doesn't print loop2 at all.

Two questions:

1. the file object returned by open(), is it an iterable? that's why it can be used in a for loop?
2. why loop2 doesn't get printed at all?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is not only an *iterable*, it is an *iterator* [1], which is why it can only traverse the file once. You may reset the file cursor with `.seek(0)` as many have suggested but you should, in most cases, only iterate a file once.

[1]: The "file" object is of class [`TextIOBase`](/https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) which is a subclass of [`IoBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase), and `IoBase` supports the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

Comment: +1 for a nice, concise description of the iterable-vs.-iterator thing (which most of the other answers didn't even attempt, even though it's the key to the question).

Comment: Thanks for that description.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, file objects are iterators.

Like all iterators, you can only loop over them *once*, after which the iterator is exhausted. Your file read pointer is at the end of the file. Re-open the file, or use `.seek(0)` to rewind the file pointer if you need to loop again.

Alternatively, try to avoid looping over a file twice; extract what you need into another datastructure (list, dictionary, set, heap, etc.) during the first loop.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, file objects are iterables but to go back to the beginning of the file you need to use `lines.seek(0)`, since after the first loop you are at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your are already at the end of the file. File objects are iterators. Once you iterate over them your are at the final position. Iterating again won't start from the beginning. If you would like to start at line one again, you need to use `lines.seek(0)`.

Comment: This is misleading. `list`s are also iterables, and yet you can iterate over them again without a `seek` or equivalent. The issue is that file objects are _iterators_ (as well as being iterables).

Comment: Typo. I meant iterator. Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better, though, to rewrite code so that the file doesn't need to be iterated twice. Read all the lines into a list of some kind, or perform all the processing in a single loop.

Comment: Yes but no. If the file is small enough it's in some buffer anyway (the in-process file buffer, the I/O buffer in the kernel, who knows). Slurping into yet another memory area in the form of a list will not necessarily improve anything. Measurements are needed.