# Combining functions in one file

Tags: python, function, printing

```
infilehandle = open ("receipts-10-28-13.txt", "r")

# FUNCTIONS

def stripsigns( astring ):
    """Remove dollar signs"""
    signs = "$"
    nosigns = ""
    for numbers in astring:
        if numbers not in signs:
            nosigns = nosigns + numbers
    return nosigns

def totaltake():
    """Calculate total take"""
    total = 0
    for line in infilehandle:
        values = line.split(':')
        cardnumbers = values[1]
        cardnumbers = stripsigns(cardnumbers)
        total = (total + eval(cardnumbers))
        total = round(total,2)
    return total

# more code etc

def computetax(rate, total):
    total = totaltake() - totaltip()
    taxed = total * rate
    taxed = round(taxed,2)
    return taxed

# more code etc

# VARS

total = totaltake()
tips = totaltip()
tax = computetax(rate,total)

rate = eval(input("Input the tax rate as an integer:"))

# PRINT

print("Total take: $", totaltake())
print("Total tips: $", totaltips())
print("Tax owed: $", computetax(rate,total))
```

I'm trying to make a file that will look at elements from a txt file and then calculate things based on the numbers in the file. The functions are all either variations of the totaltake(), which is getting numbers from the file and finding the sum, or the computetax(), which takes the numbers the other functions calculate and multiplies/divides/etc. I've tested all the functions individually and they all work, but when I try to put them together in one file, it doesn't give me the output I want, and I don't know why. It prints the value of whatever is first in the vars list, and 0 for everything else -- so for the version of code I have above, it prints

```
Total take: $ 6533.47
Total tips: $ 0
Tax owed: $ 0
```

So basically, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the expected output, and what is the input data ?

Comment: `eval(cardnumbers)` ? don't you mean `int(cardnumber)`?

Comment: I guess your issue comes from the fact that you open your input file once at the beginning, then go through it, but never reset the read pointer, makes that it points to the end of the file. You need to reopen your file at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Is file object in python an iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994568)

[File objects are iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next), meaning that once a file has been iterated to completion, you cannot iterate over the file again unless it has been reset to the beginning of the file by calling [`file.seek(0)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek).

When you only call `totaltake()`, because `infilehandle` has not yet been iterated, the for loop goes through all the lines in `infilehandle`, which is why you get the expected result.

However, when you put `computetax()` together with `totaltake()`, `totaltake()` gets called by itself, and then again in`computetax()`. Because `infilehandle` has been iterated to completion the first time `totaltake()` is called, the for loop is not entered the second time and the initial value for `total`, `0`, is returned.

As the value returned by `totaltake()` should not change, you should modify `computetax()` so that you can pass `total` as a parameter instead of calling `totaltake()`. You should do the same so that it also takes `tips` as a parameter instead of recalculating the value.

If you cannot modify `computetake()`, you could also seek to the beginning of `infilehandle` by adding `infilehandle.seek(0)` to the beginning of `totaltake()`, to allow it to be iterated again.