# Line counting in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner in Python self studying Python 2.7. May I ask one question I got in line counting codes in Python?
How do I intuitively understand why the below works, especially how I can understand what the for loop is doing with the file handle?

Many thanks all

```
fhand=open('test.txt')
count=0
for line in fhand:
    count=count+1

print count
```

Comment: Try to print each line in your file:
for line in fhand:
    print line

Comment: Did you do any research into how iteration over a file object works in Python?

Comment: And is your question about iterating over file objects, or everything in that block including variable assignment and incrementing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) returns a [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) object.

`count=0` initializes a `count` variable with the value of `0`.

As you can see in the documentation of the `file` object, using a `for` loop will get you the contents of the file line-by-line. (This is because [`file` objects are iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994568/703229).)

Each time you get the contents of a line, `count=count+1` adds `1` to the `count` variable.

`print count` dumps the contents of the `count` variable.

Comment: this more like logic and kwnolage than intuition.

Answer (score 0):

A [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) is an iterator which when used will return each line of the file. Therefore, the count in the for-loop will simply count the number of lines in the file

Answer (score 0):

```
fhand=open('test.txt') # Opens the file and puts the content of it in the "fhand" variable
count=0 # Creates new variable "count" and sets it to 0
for line in fhand:
    count=count+1 # Increase count by 1 for every line in the file

print count # Prints the amount of lines
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, when you open the file, you are getting access to its contents.

```
fhand=open('test.txt')
```

The above does the job.

```
count=0
```

When you initialize count to 0, that means the variable is set to value 0, and once it enters the loop,

```
count=count+1
```

adds +1 to it every time.

```
for line in fhand
```

Above code is for iteration. It loops over each and every line of the file fhand and for every iteration, it adds +1 to count.

When the iteration is complete, the value of count is set, which you print later to get the count of number of lines.